# php code for editing and changing an image

Tags: php, mysql

How can I replace an image file when editing a database record that contains an image?

This is my code that displays the image to be edited:

```
</tr>
          <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="style4">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $row_Member_info['image1']; ?>" width="100%" /><p align="center"><strong>Image 1</strong></td>
          </tr>
```

This is what I am trying to add to replace the image file with another image but does not work:

```
<tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="style4">Change Image1:</td>
             <td colspan="2" class="style1">Choose a file to upload: <input name="image1" type="file" /><br></td>
            <td class="style1">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
```

This is my code for updating the record which works except for replacing the image. The new image is not writing to the database and not saving to the 'uploads/' folder. Also, does not generate any error code:

```
// This displayes the selected row from the previous page
$colname_Member_info = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['recordID'])) {
$colname_Member_info = $_GET['recordID'];
}
mysql_select_db(strato11_members);
$query_Member_info = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Member_info WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Member_info, "text"));
$Member_info = mysql_query($query_Member_info) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Member_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($Member_info);
$totalRows_Member_info = mysql_num_rows($Member_info);

// Form1 starts here to update the selected record
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

// added by Jim to set image formats

     function GetImageExtension($imagetype) {
        if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
        switch($imagetype) {
            case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
            case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
            case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
            case 'image/png': return '.png';
            default: return false;
        }
    } 

// added by JK to process image1
$target = "uploads/"; 
    if (isset($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"]) && !empty($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"])) {
        $temp_name=$_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"];
        $imgtype=$_FILES["image1"]["type"];
        $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);

//This is the directory where images will be saved 
        if (!$ext) die("Upload file format is not allowed");
        $target1 = $target . basename( $_FILES['image1']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target1)) {
        } else {
            exit("Error While uploading image on the server"); 
        }
    }

// JK code ends

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE `Member_info` SET name=%s, rank=%s, departed=%s, service=%, lodd=%s, veteran=%s, branch=%s, decorated=%s, comments=%s, image1=%, cemetery=%s WHERE id=%s",                
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['rank'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['departed'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['service'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['lodd'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['veteran'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['branch'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['decorated'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['comments'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['cemetery'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($target1,"text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "text"));



// code for entering it into a database.
    mysql_select_db(strato11_members);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL) or die(mysql_error());

$updateGoTo = "view_members.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}
```

Comment: You code is suseptable to SQL injection. Also, you are using the mysql functions which are depreciated. Use either PDO or mysqli functions and prepared statements. Have you tried echoing the parameters passed to your PHP script to make sure you're getting the correct values? Have you checked to see if the file is actually uploaded to the server?

Comment: I know that there are better ways of writing this but this is all I've learned so far from years ago. Everything passes except for the image upload and no, the file was not uploaded to the server. I'm only having an issue when I want to edit the record and change the image.

Comment: If the file isn't uploaded to the server, then your code won't run since there's no filename to be seen. Without seeing the form tag, there's no way to see if your HTML is correct.

Comment: Maybe chat directly to give you credentials?

Answer (score 0):

In your `form` tag did you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Because this is the most thing that programmer forgot to use this when we use `input type='file'`.
So First of all check `enctype` in `form` tag that you used or not if not then please use this and hope it will upload your file.

Comment: No, so let me give that a try.

Comment: I added:  "code"   <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: That passed a value of zero to the image1 field as opposed to the correct value which should be: uploads/my-new-image.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this function helps...

```
function upload($tempFile,$afile)
{   
    $ip = trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 

    // what file types do you want to disallow?
    $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".php5", ".exe", ".js", ".inc");
     // allowed filetypes       
    $allowed_filetypes = array('.bmp','.png','.jpg','.gif','.doc','.rtf','.txt','.pdf','.avi','.DOC','.docx','.DOCX','.RTF','.TXT','.PDF','.AVI','.ppt','.PPT','.pptx','.PPTX','.PNG');
    $errors = []; // Store errors here
    $currentdir=getcwd();
    $uploaddir = $currentdir . "/uploaded/"; //Upload directory: needs write premissions
    $log = "uploadlog.txt"; // Upload LOG file
    if (!is_dir($uploaddir)) {
        die ("Upload directory does not exist. " . $uploaddir);
    }
    if (!is_writable($uploaddir)) {
        die ("Upload directory is not writable.");
    }
    foreach ($blacklist as $item)   
    {
        if (preg_match("/$item\$/i", $afile))
        {
            echo "Invalid filetype !";
                $date = date("m/d/Y");
                $time = date("h:i:s A");                 
                $fp = fopen($log,"ab");
                fwrite($fp,"$ip | ".$afile." | $date | $time | INVALID TYPE"."\r\n");
                fclose($fp);
            unset($afile);
            exit;
        }
    }
    // Get the extension from the filename.
    $ext = substr($afile, strpos($afile,'.'), strlen($afile)-1); 
    
// Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes)){
                $date = date("m/d/Y");
                $time = date("h:i:s A");                     
                $fp = fopen($log,"ab");
                fwrite($fp,"$ip | ".basename($afile)." | $date | $time | INVALID TYPE"."\r\n");
                fclose($fp);
        die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
    }
        
        // Proceed with file upload
        if (is_uploaded_file($tempFile))
        {
            //File was uploaded to the temp dir, continue upload process
        if (move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $uploaddir . $afile))
            {
                // Now log the uploaders IP adress date and time
                $date = date("m/d/Y");
                $time = date("h:i:s A");               
                $fp = fopen($log,"ab");
                fwrite($fp,"$ip | ".$afile." | $date | $time | OK"."\r\n");
                fclose($fp);
            } else {
                echo "Error while uploading the file, Please contact the webmaster.";
                unset($tempFile);
            }
        } 
             
    }//end func
```

// use this function like below

```
$fileTmpName  = $_FILES['personal_photo']['tmp_name'];
upload($fileTmpName,$personal_photo);
```